# rasterVis polygon under raster layer in R

Tags: raster, r

I want to plot both a raster layer and a polygon layer using `rasterVis::levelplot()`, however, I want to have the polygon layer appear under the raster layer.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 1, ymn = 0, ymx = 1, nrows = 100, ncols = 100,
            crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
r[] <- rnorm(100 * 100)
r[sample(1:ncell(r), ncell(r) / 2)] <- NA

pt <- data.frame(x = 0.5, y = 0.5)
coordinates(pt) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(pt) <- projection(r)
pt_buff <- gBuffer(pt, width = 0.25)
levelplot(r, margin = FALSE) +
  layer(sp.polygons(pt_buff, fill = "grey40", col = NA))
```

I want the circle **under** the raster layer:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `under = TRUE` inside the [`layer`](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/layer.html) function, or the wrapper function `layer_`:

```
levelplot(r, margin = FALSE) +
    layer_(sp.polygons(pt_buff,
                      fill = "grey40",
                      col = NA))
```

Comment: Thanks! Switching this to the accepted answer, since it more succinctly answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can create custom panel functions in [lattice](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lattice)-based plot functions:

```
levelplot(r, margin = FALSE,
          panel=function(...) {
            sp.polygons(pt_buff, fill = "grey40", col = NA)
            panel.levelplot(...)
          })
```

[image: levelplot]

Comment: thanks, this is perfect! I know nothing about `lattice` plotting, so never would have come across this on my own